# Select and print multiple sheets in one print job Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have inherited this awfulness, and been asked to make updates.

Currently this workbook is built with one sheet that has a bunch of checkboxes, all associated with other sheets in the workbook. The user selects checkboxes, and then hits a button to print the sheets associated with each checkbox that is checked.

**The way it's built now, it runs a print job for each sheet selected. I have been asked to run one print job for all sheets selected (to avoid having a hundred cover sheets).**

I have written a little VBA function that produces a string containing the name of every sheet for which the checkbox is checked, in quotes, comma separated.

I need to figure out a way to use this information to select all the sheets and then print once each sheet I need is selected.

Or even hell, I'd take being able to spit this string back into the macro that was originally written for the print ability. Right now the macro is another sheet in the workbook, and has 102 different print commands, controlled by a bunch of if statements. So I'd take being about to spit the string into that sheet so I could run one print command.

Either way, someone please help.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function sheetString()
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim sConcat As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For c = 2 To 6 Step 2
        For r = 1 To 46
            If Sheet94.Cells(r, c) = True Then
               sConcat = sConcat & Sheet94.Cells(r, c - 1) & ", "
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

    sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 2)

    Debug.Print sConcat
End Function
```

The output of the code is like this (with varying names depending on which boxes are checked):

> "PR015", "PR018", "PR019", "PR026", "PR029A"

EDIT: Thanks to simoco, I'm closer than I've been so far. Here is the code as it stands now.

```
Public Function sheetString()
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim sConcat As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet94

    For c = 2 To 6 Step 2
        For r = 1 To 46
            If ws.Cells(r, c) = True Then
               sConcat = sConcat & ws.Cells(r, c - 1) & ","
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
    sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 1)
    Debug.Print sConcat
    sheetString = sConcat
End Function

Sub test()
    'if cells with sheet names contains quotes
    'Sheets(Split(Replace(sheetString, """", ""), ",")).Select
    'if cells with sheet names doesn't contain quotes
    Sheets(Split(sheetString, ",")).Select
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

It's running without bombing out, but now it's only selecting the first sheet that has it's box checked.

Comment: does your cells `Sheet94.Cells(r, c - 1)` contains sheet names _with quotes_: `"SheetName"`?

Comment: Yes they do, but I can change that if need be.

Comment: As you might have noticed, I am very new to VB and am not really comfortable with the syntax yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is slightly modified function `sheetString`:

```
Public Function sheetString()
    Dim c As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim sConcat As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet94

    For c = 2 To 6 Step 2
        For r = 1 To 46
            If ws.Cells(r, c) Then
               sConcat = sConcat & ws.Cells(r, c - 1) & ","
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

    sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 1)

    Debug.Print sConcat
    sheetString = sConcat
End Function
```

and then call use it like this:

```
Sub test()
    'if cells with sheet names contains quotes
    'Sheets(Split(Replace(sheetString, """", ""), ",")).PrintOut Copies:=1
    'if cells with sheet names doesn't contain quotes
    Sheets(Split(sheetString, ",")).PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question. So do I just create the sub test() in it's own module, and then assign it to the 'print selected sheets' button?

Comment: there is no need to create additional module, you can place `sub test()` in the same module where do you have your function `sheetString()`. Aand yes, then you can assign `sub test()` to the button

Comment: Well... It allowed me assign that to my button, but I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error. I think it's because the Sheets function won't take multiple arguments, but that's a total guess, based on me trying to shove a bunch of values into it before.

Comment: You have still gotten me even closer tho! At least now I have the button communicating with my VB! And for that I thank you.

Comment: 1) check your function, there should be `sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 1)` instead `sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 2)`. 2) you can use `Sheets` with array of sheet names, there is no problem with it. 3) and also check what output you get in line `Debug.Print sConcat`.

Comment: Well I had noticed that when I am putting multiple arguments into anything that it's automatically putting a space after each comma, so I adjusted my concatenation to do the same thinking that might be why it's bombing on me, hence the -2 (because it's cutting off the space and the comma on the end)

Comment: Wait.... it's not bombing out anymore, but it's only printing the first sheet. :-/

Comment: ok, I've figured it out..change `ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1` to `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1`..see my updated answer

Comment: Actually I got it to work. I took what you did here and the line that says:  
`Sheets(Split(sheetString, ",")).Select`  
I changed it to:  
`Sheets(Split(sheetString, ",")).PrintOut`  
and it worked! All thanks to you Simico. I know I didn't go with precisely, line by line, what you suggested, but it's close enough that I feel like your answer is the correct one. It's not like a faux pas to mark your answer as correct right?

Comment: Well yes, Your answer is definitely what got me here. Thanks a lot. As for my previous comment, I give up on the damn line breaks....

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Macro1()
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
End Sub
Sub Macro()
  Worksheets.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Use this code to print all sheets in xl. Also select your specific `pri`