# Excel VBA: Selecting Multiple worksheets based on the results of a userform - for updating and printing

Tags: excel, dynamic, worksheet, vba

I am creating an excel workbook to be used for clients where the sheet tabs will be hidden. I would like to have a userform pop up where clients select which sheets they would like in checkboxes and for these to then be selected together (so that the page numbering is updated) as well as printed continuously.

From other options I've seen, I have Populated a specific sheet with the names of the Sheet Names as so:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Set PP = Worksheets("Printing Page")
Dim CB1 As Worksheet
Set CB1 = Worksheets("Retail, Mall, Shopping Centres")
Dim CB2 As Worksheet
Set CB2 = Worksheets("Sports & Social Clubs")

    'Clear & Populate the sheet
    PP.Cells.Clear

    PP.Cells(1, 1).Value = Chr(34) & CB1.Name & Chr(34)
    PP.Cells(2, 1).Value = Chr(34) & CB2.Name & Chr(34)


    'Check each checkbox and enter the sheet number in PP

    If Me.CBRetailMallSC = False Then
        PP.Rows(1).Delete
    End If

     If Me.CBSportsSocial = False Then
        PP.Rows(2).Delete
    End If
```

From there i've tried turning these values into an array and transposing or running a function like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156594/select-and-print-multiple-sheets-in-one-print-job-excel-vba).
However I always get an error message saying "Run time error 9 - subscript out of range" and pointing to the Sheets(x).Select line of code.

Please please help, i am completely and utterly lost!!!

PS: if only one checkbox is selected then everything runs fine, but as soon as 2  then it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the idea that the client uses the checkboxes to choose which hidden sheets they would like to print out?  And you want to print them out as a single document instead of several different documents?

If so this is the logic you'll need.  You are correct in having a special page to copy the other pages to.  (I don't understand why you are deleting rows form the "PP" page though.)  You can add headers and footers with page numbers on your print page.  You only need to keep track of the last used row on the print sheet.

For each sheet the client selects, copy the used range.  (It helps to keep the width within a normal sheet size, or you can programmatically force it to print
full page size.)  Paste the first copied sheet to row "A" of the print sheet.  Find the last used row of the print sheet and add 1 row.  Put a page break there.  Add another row and paste the second selected sheet to that row, and so forth.